I cannot create a pre-filled form in python django
I am doing a simple project to practice CRUD in Django and I am working on a simple "To Do" project and these area my codes.
models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class ToDoList(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False , blank = False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , null = True , blank = True )
    date = models.DateField(null = True , blank = True )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 
    

forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from django import forms 
from .models import ToDoList

class ToDoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta : 
        model = ToDoList
        fields = ['title','description','date']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'description':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
        }

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.homepage,name = 'home_page'),
    path("add-new",views.add_todo,name = 'add_new'),
    path("delete-todo/<todo_id>",views.delete_todo,name = "delete_todo"),
    path("update_todo/<todo_id>",views.update_todo,name = "update_todo"),
]


views.py
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect 
from .forms import ToDoForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import ToDoList

# Codes for the homepage

def homepage(request):
    todos = ToDoList.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html' , {'todos':todos})

# Codes for the add new todo

def add_todo(request):
    form = ToDoForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ToDoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,("Added new todo"))
            return redirect('home_page')
        else:
            print('not valid')
            return render(request,'addnew.html', {'form':form})
    
    return render(request,"addnew.html", {"form":form})

# Codes for the update todo (not working properly)

def update_todo(request, todo_id):
    todos = ToDoList.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ToDoForm(request.POST, instance = todos)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            return redirect("home_page")
    else:
        form = ToDoForm(instance=todos)

    return render(request , "updatetodo.html", {"form":form, "todos":todos})

# code for deleting todo
def delete_todo(request, todo_id):
    todos = ToDoList.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        todos.delete()
        return redirect('home_page')
    else:
        return redirect('home_page')

all the functions work fine except Update Todo. I followed all the steps on to create a pre filled form and its not showing me anything just "The fields are empty oh also this is the html file
updatetodo.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {{todos.title}}

    <form action = "" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{form.as_p}}

        <div class = "text-center">
           <button class = "btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}


index.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for todo in todos %}
        <form action = "{% url 'delete_todo' todo.id %}" method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <form action = "{% url 'update_todo' todo.id %}" method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>

        {{todo.title}}
        {{todo.description}}
        {{todo.date}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock  %}


please help me find the solution for it.
I used google, django - documentation and followed the steps of this random ytber and still it didn't work.
Maybe im just bad at understanding english who knows.

Are you sure the object you are editing really has data because all the fields can be empty.

@Benbb96 yes I am sure.

I'm curious as to how you are passing todo_id to the def update_todo(request, todo_id): view.  Can you edit your question to show your index.html file.  You state you are sure that the instance has data.  You see this in the admin panel?  Are you sure the id in the admin panel is the same as the one in the url for updatetodo?

@raphael I updated it. Have a look at the index.html at the end

Try updating you index.html like this:
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for todo in todos %}
        <form action = "{% url 'delete_todo' todo.id %}" method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <a href="{% url 'update_todo' todo.id %}" class = "btn btn-primary">Update</button>

        {{todo.title}}
        {{todo.description}}
        {{todo.date}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock  %}

To access the edit page, you don't need to use a form button, a simple link will trigger a GET request and display your pre-filled form. With the form button, it was like you already submitted the form with empty data.

IT TOOK ME TWO DAYS FOR  SOLUTIONS AND I WAS NOT SMART ENOUGH TO FIND THIS ONE THANK  VERY MUCH

Ha ha don't be too hard on yourself, it happens to everyone and that's the process to learn

Add id to your ToDoList model:
class ToDoList(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False , blank = False)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000 , null = True , blank = True )
date = models.DateField(null = True , blank = True )
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

and for urls.py :
path("delete-todo/<str:pk>/",views.delete_todo,name = "delete_todo"),
path("update_todo/<str:pk>/",views.update_todo,name = "update_todo"),

and get id by pk in your view code if you copy these urls.

I'm getting an error with this

what is your err?

ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string –
